# trying to convert this C++ code to C code, having a problem with the fflush() function

Tags: c++, c, file, input

I'm trying to convert this C++ code to C code, but I'm having a problem with the fflush() function.

What is wrong?

How can I use another function?

```cpp
#include <iostream.h>
#include <time.h>
#include<dos.h>
int main()
{
    cout << "Loading";
    cout.flush();
    for (int j=0; j<2; ++j) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            cout << ".";
            cout.flush();
            sleep(1);
        }
        cout << "\b\b\b   \b\b\b";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

```c
#include <stdio.h>>
#include <unistd.h>
int main()
{
   printf("Loading");
    fflush();
    for (int j=0; j<2; ++j){
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            printf(".");
            fflush();
            sleep(1);
        }
       printf("\b\b\b   \b\b\b");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Be explicit: `fprintf(stdout, "Loading");` and `fflush(stdout);` notice both start with the letter `f` indicating they need a FILE* (If I remember my C correctly).

Answer (score 3):

`fflush` takes an argument - the stream it is supposed to flush. You'd need to use `fflush(stdout)`.

Another problem is that the C++ code is *semantically* wrong too. Rather than using `cout` or `printf` to `stdout`, for such diagnostic messages one would be using `cerr`/`stderr`, which should be unbuffered anyway . using that you wouldn't probably need the `fflush`. I.e.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Loading");
    for (int j=0; j<2; ++j){
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            fprintf(stderr, ".");
            sleep(1);
        }
        fprintf(stderr, "\b\b\b   \b\b\b");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`fflush` needs file pointer as argument. This would flush the local buffer data(stored in primary memory - mostly dram) corresponding to the file into the actual file stored in the secondary storage.
For your case use `fflush(stdout)`